# Database getting 2 columns instead of 1 when fetching data

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm pretty new with databases, so sorry if this is a dumb mistake/question. So I'm trying to pull data from my database, yet every time I try, e.g get the category, it pulls the category, re loops, and gets the title as well? Here is my code to retrieve the data (the code that's pulling both sets of data instead of just the one)

```
public ArrayList<String> get_all_Categories()
{

    String get_Cats_Query = "SELECT item_category from " + TABLE_ITEMS;

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(get_Cats_Query, null);

    cats_from_db = new ArrayList<String>() {};

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) //if cursor is on the first value
        {
            do{ 
                if(!cats_from_db.contains(cursor.getString(0))) 
                {
                        cats_from_db.add(cursor.getString(0));
                }
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext()); 
        }

    cursor.close();

    }
```

Here is where I put the data in: I've debugged this and all the items seem to be going to the right slots:

```
public void Add_Item(New_Item_db new_item)
{
    ContentValues item_values = new ContentValues();
    item_values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, new_item.get_itemCategory());
    item_values.put(COLUMN_PRICE, new_item.get_itemPrice());
    item_values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, new_item.get_itemTitle());
    item_values.put(COLUMN_VENDOR, new_item.get_itemVendor());
    item_values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, new_item.get_itemImage());
    //get and add the created items to the database
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, item_values);  database

    db.close();
}
```

Here is my `onCreate` for the DB:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{

    String Create_query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + "("
            + COLUMN_INDEX + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_VENDOR + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB" +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(Create_query);
}
```

If anyone can help me figure out why when I try to pull all the categories out into a list, I get Category, Title, Category, Title etc rather than just Category, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This code looks OK; it reads all values in the `item_category` column. Check the database.